# ambigious implicits value - twirl form error

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.6, twirl

With playframework 2.6, I am getting following errors. I have read and found this error only on [older versions](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-bootstrap/issues/32), that too resolved easily.

[image]

```
[error] /Users/vishalupadhyay/Work/app/views/login_form.scala.html:12:22: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both method implicitJavaMessages in object PlayMagicForJava of type => play.api.i18n.Messages
[error]  and value request of type play.api.mvc.MessagesRequestHeader
[error]  match expected type play.api.i18n.MessagesProvider
[error]     @helper.inputText(loginForm("password"))
[error]                      ^
```

Could not find any answer which can help it. Please see complete code in this [link](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/play-framework-2-6-compile-error-with-twirl-ambiguous-implicit-value-play-api-mvc-messagesrequestheader/3727).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the implicit `Lang` and `Messages` arguments

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have added the code link. Please check and update the answer. I have done above to make it work but getting same error.